# Why am I getting a A facade root has not been set RuntimeException in my Laravel package?

Tags: laravel

I am implementing a Laravel 7 package but when running my unit test, I am getting a RuntimeException

```
{
    "name": "",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "email": ""
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
        "illuminate/config": "^7.19",
        "illuminate/contracts": "^7.19",
        "illuminate/http": "^7.19",
        "moneyphp/money": "^3.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "QuickPay\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "QuickPay\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "dev-master",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "pestphp/pest": "^0.2.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    }
}
```

The class I am testing

```
namespace QuickPay\Ping;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class Ping {
    /**
     * Send ping request to https://api.quickpay.net/ping
     */
    public static function send() {
        $response = Http::get('https://api.quickpay.net/ping');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

My Unit test

```
use QuickPay\Ping\Ping;

test('ping request returns pong', function () {
    assertEquals([], Ping::send());
});
```

The exception

```
• Tests\Unit\PingTest > ping request returns pong
   RuntimeException 

  A facade root has not been set.

  at vendor/illuminate/support/Facades/Facade.php:258
    254▕     {
    255▕         $instance = static::getFacadeRoot();
    256▕ 
    257▕         if (! $instance) {
  ➜ 258▕             throw new RuntimeException('A facade root has not been set.');
    259▕         }
    260▕ 
    261▕         return $instance->$method(...$args);
    262▕     }

  1   src/Ping/Ping.php:16
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic("get")

  2   tests/Unit/PingTest.php:6
      QuickPay\Ping\Ping::send()
```

I have run the composer dump-autoload command.